I am trying to connect with concox v5 gps terminal
I am working on a PHP script to communicate with a Concox V5 GPS tracking device. While I am able to receive the login packet successfully, I am not receiving the heartbeat and location packets. Below is my PHP code for the TCP/IP socket server:
<?php
$host = '0.0.0.0'; // Listen on all interfaces
$port = 5023;

// Create a TCP Stream socket
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

// Bind the socket to an address/port
socket_bind($sock, $host, $port) or die('Could not bind to address');

// Start listening for connections
socket_listen($sock);

// Create a loop to keep the server running
while (true) {
    // Accept incoming connection
    $client = socket_accept($sock);

    // Read the input from the client
    $raw = socket_read($client, 1024);

    // Print received data
    echo "\nReceived data: $raw\n";
    
    $hexData = bin2hex($raw);
    
    echo "\nHex Data : $hexData\n";

    $start_bit = substr($hexData, 0, 4);
    $length = substr($hexData, 4, 2);
    $protocolNumber = substr($hexData, 6, 2);

    if ($protocolNumber == '01') {
        echo "Protocol Number : $protocolNumber\n";
        echo "Login Packet\n";
        $terminalId = substr($hexData, 8, 16);
        $imei = substr($hexData, 9, 15);
        $info_content = substr($hexData, 8, 24);
        $model_check = substr($hexData, 24, 4);
        $time_zone = substr($hexData, 28, 4);
        $info_serial_number = substr($hexData, 32, 4);
        $error_check = substr($hexData, 36, 4);
        $stop_bit = substr($hexData, 40, 4);

        $data_for_checksum = substr($hexData, 4, 32);
        $binary_data_for_checksum = hex2bin($data_for_checksum);

        $newString = chr(0x05).chr(0x01).hex2bin($info_serial_number);
        $crc16 = GetCrc16($newString, strlen($newString));
        $crc16h = floor($crc16 / 256);
        $crc16l = $crc16 - $crc16h * 256;
        
        $crc = sprintf('%02x%02x', $crc16h, $crc16l);

        echo "########################################################\n";
        echo "Start Bit : $start_bit\n";
        echo "Length : $length\n";
        echo "Protocol Number : $protocolNumber\n";
        echo "Information Content : $info_content\n";
        echo "Terminal ID : $terminalId\n";
        echo "Model Check : $model_check\n";
        echo "Time Zone : $time_zone\n";
        echo "IMEI : $imei\n";
        echo "Info Serial Number : $info_serial_number\n";
        echo "Error Check : $error_check\n";
        echo "Stop Bit : $stop_bit\n";
        echo "Data for Checksum : $data_for_checksum\n";
        echo "-------------------------------------------------------\n";
        
        echo "New String : $newString\n";
        echo "CRC16 Calculated : $crc16\n";
        echo "crc16h : $crc16h\n";
        echo "crc16l : $crc16l\n";
        echo "Final CRC16 Calculated : $crc\n";
        echo "-------------------------------------------------------\n";

        echo "########################################################\n";

        // Optionally, you can send a response back to the client
        $res1 = '78780501';  
        $res2 = $info_serial_number; 
        $res3 = $crc;
        $res4 = '0d0a'; 
        $sendCommands = $res1.$res2.$res3.$res4;
        echo "Response from Server : ".$sendCommands."\n";

        $send_cmd = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($sendCommands); $i += 2) {
            $send_cmd .= chr(hex2bin(substr($sendCommands, $i, 2)));
        }

        socket_send($client, $send_cmd, strlen($send_cmd), 0);

        // Close the client socket
        socket_close($client);
    } elseif ($protocolNumber == '12') {
        echo "Protocol Number : $protocolNumber\n";
    } elseif ($protocolNumber == '13') {
        echo "Protocol Number : $protocolNumber\n";
    } elseif ($protocolNumber == '15') {
        echo "Protocol Number : $protocolNumber\n";
    } elseif ($protocolNumber == '16') {
        echo "Protocol Number : $protocolNumber\n";
    } else {
        echo "Protocol Number : $protocolNumber\n";
    }
}

// Close the master socket
socket_close($sock);

// CRC16-CCITT (XModem) checksum calculation
function GetCrc16($data, $length) {
    $crc = 0xFFFF;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $crc ^= ord($data[$i]);
        for ($j = 0; $j < 8; $j++) {
            if ($crc & 0x0001) {
                $crc = ($crc >> 1) ^ 0x8408;
            } else {
                $crc >>= 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return $crc;
}
?>

Issue:

I am successfully receiving and processing the login packet.
I am not receiving any heartbeat (0x23), location (0x12), or other packets from the device after the initial login.

Questions:

Is there anything wrong with my server implementation that might be causing the issue?
Do I need to send any specific acknowledgment or keep-alive packets to continue receiving data?
Is there a specific protocol sequence I need to follow after the login packet to receive other types of packets?

Any insights or suggestions to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Output like :

Hex Data : 78780d0103509253775940270018245a0d0a
Protocol Number : 01
Login Packet
########################################################
Start Bit : 7878
Length : 0d
Protocol Number : 01
Information Content : 0350925377594027
Terminal ID : 0350925377594027
IMEI : 350925377594027
Info Serial Number : 0018
Error Check : 245a
Stop Bit : 0d0a
Data for Checksum : 0d0103509253775940270018
-------------------------------------------------------
New String : 0018
CRC16 Calculated : 12449
crc16h : 48
crc16l : 161
Final CRC16 Calculated : 30a1
-------------------------------------------------------
########################################################
Response from Server : 78780501001830a10d0a
Sent


Normally when the device is connected to your server, it needs to send data(TCP) while sockets is open, and I saw in your code that you close the socket when you receive 01, but the connection need to continue the device need to send more coords data..., the hearbeat only means that server or devices is there...
